# Tour link in Meta top bar is confusing

Tags: feature-request, support, hyperlinks, top-bar

In the new SE Top Bar, the Tour link in the MSO help menu just links to the about page.  This is obviously because meta does not have it's own tour and `/tour` is the same as `/about`.

But to the uninformed, this can be confusing.  Instead can we:

1. Redirect to main site [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
2. Change the dropdown link label from "Tour" to "About".

I already [posted](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2777/tour-link-not-working-properly-on-meta) in Drupal Meta, but in Drupal answers the tour page redirected to help page.

[image]

Comment: Tour = about. Check [/tour](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tour) and [/about](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: I favor changing the label in the dropdown to "About".  Because Meta SO is so special, redirecting to the SO Tour would be confusing

Comment: @Bala, I thought the wording of your question was somewhat confusing, so I took the liberty to change it to what I think you were asking.  Please don't hesitate to roll back if I didn't capture what you were trying to say.  Your original wording made it sound like you were questioning the lack of a tour instead of the fact that it was confusing.

Comment: @psubsee2003 thanks psubsee now it is more clear!!!

Comment: @psubsee2003: and probably would increase the chance of us seeing "_PLZ fix IOS bUg iN My CODEz_" questions here.

Comment: Looks like this is no longer an issue? The Tour and Help Center have separate links in that dropdown, and both seem to work fine now.