# Tour & Help Center link are same in Area 51

Tags: discussion, bug, area-51, tour

[Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/) help menu links redirect to [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) page. Both the [Tour](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) and [Help Center](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) links are linked to FAQ page Is this correct behavior or bug ?

Comment: related http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2777/tour-link-redirect-to-diffrent-page

Comment: Nimesh your question looks confusing that's why I think you got negative vote and I raised this question already here: [Tour link in Meta top bar is confusing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211556/tour-link-in-meta-top-bar-is-confusing) - but it now working properly in MSO, but rest of the sites are not solved yet!.

Comment: @Bala have you checked the above link in Area 51 site? If you have understood then can you update my question?

Comment: Nimes I updated the question but it needs approval from you or from reviewers.

Comment: Looks like this is no longer an issue? In Area 51 Discussions, that dropdown now only has a "Help Center" link (which redirects to the FAQ); the "Tour" link (which would also redirect to the FAQ) no longer appears in that dropdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a bug report: [Broken link to Area 51 "What's Meta" page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216390/broken-link-to-area-51-whats-meta-page)

> We won't show that link at all as of next build.
>
> There are already two links in the Help dropdown that take folks to /faq on Area 51, so a third one really isn't necessary. Not to mention that "meta" as a concept doesn't really apply to Area 51.

So although it's not explicitly stated that this is the desired behaviour, I think we can assume that they don't consider it to be a bug for now, or at least not one that they think needs addressing.